# Fullcalendar - It's possible to add prev and next buttons in the slotLabelContent ? See screenshot

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

It's possible to add prev and next buttons in the slotLabelContent like this

[image]

Here my options :

```
calendarOptions: {
    locale: frLocale,
    plugins: [resourceTimelinePlugin, momentPlugin],
    height: 680,
    headerToolbar: false,
    views: {
        resourceTimeline: {
            type: 'timeline',
            duration: {weeks: 1},
            slotDuration: {days: 1},
            titleFormat: '[Semaine] W - YYYY',
            slotLabelContent: (arg) => {
                let DD = moment(arg.date).format('DD');
                let ddd = moment(arg.date).format('ddd');
                let el = document.createElement('span');
                el.classList.add('fc-custom-slot-label');
                el.innerHTML = `<span class="fc-custom-day-number">${DD} </span><span class="fc-custom-day-week">${ddd}</span>`;
                return {domNodes: [el]}
            }

        },
    },
    initialView: 'resourceTimeline',
    schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
    resourceAreaHeaderContent: (arg) => {
        return arg.view.title;
    },
    resourceGroupField: 1,
    resourceGroupLabelContent: ['test gsgffd', 'sdfgdfgfd'],
    resources: []
}
```

And here my component :

[image]

**I use vuejs and fullcalendar/vue**

Thanks

Comment: No I don't think that's possible unfortunately. You can only put those buttons into the header. See https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features if you want to request an enhancement to fullCalendar.

Comment: I found a solution with vuejs slot and a condition on the date range https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v4#vue-connector

`<template v-slot:slotLabelContent="arg"> <div v- if="moment(arg.date).isSame(arg.view.currentStart)">....<\div></template>`

Thank for your consideration

Comment: If you found a working solution please add it below as an answer for the benefit of others with full details of how to implement it :-).